# Why expect is able to interact with `getpass` call?

Tags: python, linux, tty, getpass

I am surprised about way of working `getpass()`. I am using it in `python`, however I am aware of the fact that it is about https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpass call in reality. Moreover, I am aware of the fact that `ssh-add` uses it as well.

It is not easy to think about from many causes.

  1.

> The getpass() function opens /dev/tty (the controlling terminal of the process), outputs the string prompt, turns off echoing, reads one line (the "password"), restores the terminal state and closes /dev/tty again.

What does it mean? It opens new terminal? `/dev/tty/` is opened before `getpass` call?
What does it mean that it restore terminal state?

2. Why does expect can work with `ssh-add` or `getpass` while as `echo` does not?
   Let's consider:

```
#getpass.py 
import getpass

password = getpass.getpass()
print password
```

---

```
    [user@host ~]$ python2.7 ~/getpass.py 
    Password: 
    somepassword
```

It works. Why? I was able to type password from keybord so I guess that it has read from `stdin`. After all, the promise was about reading password `/dev/tty`, not `stdin`.

---

```
[user@host ~]$ python2.7 ~/getpass.py # we allow it to wait for password and let check to new bash session
[user@host ~]$ # new bash session
[user@host ~]$ python2.7 ~/getpass.py
[user@host ~]$ pgrep python
21502
[user@host ~]$ ls -al /proc/21502/fd
razem 0
dr-x------ 2 user wheel  0 04-14 17:55 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 user wheel  0 04-14 17:53 ..
lrwx------ 1 user wheel 64 04-14 17:55 0 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 user wheel 64 04-14 17:55 1 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 user wheel 64 04-14 17:55 2 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 user wheel 64 04-14 17:55 3 -> /dev/tty
[user@host ~]$ echo 'some_password' > /proc/21502/fd/0 #stdin of python process
[user@host ~]$ echo 'some_password' > /proc/21502/fd/3
some_password # it prins some_password here, I know why (driver of `/dev/tty` check which process call it)
```

It does **not** work.
I have no idea how `expect` tool can work (I checked it and it works). Can anyone explain it, please?

Comment: Could you explain what `getpass` change in terminal? Why expect is able to write to `/dev/tty` of another process? Emulation make matter more complex ;)

Comment: What do you mean, "of another process"? `expect` creates its own TTY, which the child processes it starts inherit and write to.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why?

`expect` acts as a terminal program. As such, it allocates a pseudoterminal (a PTY), and sets that as the active terminal for programs it starts. On Linux, this is done with [`openpty()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openpty.3.html).

Thus, software which (like `getpass`) interact directly with the terminal instead of going through stdout and stderr are handled by `expect`.

Comment: Is `expect` like `terminator` ?

Comment: Insofar as they both create PTYs that the programs run within them interact with, yes.

Comment: If you want to see a much simpler program that does the same thing, take a look at [EmPTY](http://empty.sf.net).

Comment: When I start `terminator` or `expect`  it talk to `kernel`: give me a pseudo terminal (`/dev/pts`)  device ?

Comment: Yes. See the source of EmPTY at https://github.com/ierton/empty/blob/master/empty.c, or any of the other programs mentioned; in particular, the use of [`openpty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openpty.3.html)

Comment: So I understand it like:

Comment: > I am `expect` and I will allocate some pseudoterminal. Now, all processes executed from me will be started with `stdin/stdout/stderr` attached to this pseudoterminal.  

Yeah?

Comment: Yes, *and* when they open `/dev/tty` to talk to the terminal directly (like `getpass` does), that also goes to the pseudoterminal.

Comment: What does it mean directly? Without `pts`?

Comment: Does terminals are property of process? I know that `stdin,stdout,stderr` are some property of process. However, process is aware of being attached to some terminal?

Comment: In other words, `sendline` is about `write` to some descriptor. From what, `expect` know where to write?

Comment: Yes, a process has a "controlling terminal", which is indeed a property thereof. `/dev/tty` refers to whichever terminal is the controlling terminal of a given process.

Comment: But no, `write` doesn't refer to it. `write` is passed a file descriptor number, which it looks up in the FD table. It's when opening `/dev/tty` that the controlling terminal is looked up and used to generate a file descriptor that looks at it; when `write` is called, that work is already done.

Comment: so `getpass` call can change controlling terminal? I understand that `getpass` read password from `/dev/tty`.

Comment: I never said that getpass can change the controlling terminal. `expect` can change the controlling terminal. Correct, getpass reads from `/dev/tty`.

Comment: Is it possible to deal with passing password to `getpass()` without `expect` like tools?

Comment: There's a long answer (basically, "yes, if you do things that are even more invasive / even less portable"), but the short answer is "no". Anyhow, it's not something you should be trying to do in the first place; depending on the details of the use case, there's generally a better-practice alternative somewhere.